# Atalho do Windows em conflito com Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows-10

Estou usando o [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/). Ao tentar formatar o código com o atalho <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, ao invés dele indentar o código Java, ele abre **a tela de acesso remoto do Windows**, como pode ver na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O comportamento não faz nenhum sentido, parece que os atalhos do sistema operacional Windows estão em conflito com as teclas de atalhos do Eclipse.

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: No Eclipse não é Shift+TAB para indentar o código seleccionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> parece que os atalhos do sistema operacional Windows estão em conflito com as teclas de atalhos do Eclipse.

Realmente está havendo um conflito ao realizar esse atalho. Utilizo Eclipse e tenho alguns colegas que também utilizam tentei e pedi para tentarem reproduzir o erro, e não tivemos o mesmo problema. Talvez, esteja relacionado com o seu Eclipse.

Certifique que sua janela do Eclipse está maximizada e selecionada.

**Solução 1:** Você pode estar tentando alterar seus atalhos no Eclipse, através do menu General > Keys.

Procurar pelo atalho que já está definido como padrão, no caso  Ctrl+Shift+F está relacionado a indentação e alterar para outra sequência de teclas.

[Neste link](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Faccessibility%2Fkeyboardshortcuts.htm) você poderá encontrar na sessão **Customizing Key bindings** como realizar a personalização com mais detalhes.

**Solução 2:** Atualizar o Eclipse, e/ou reinstalar o seu Eclipse.

Comment: Desculpe @Pedro Duca, na sua postagem você menciona um link que diz como resolver meu problema, porém não consigo visualizar o link, onde está, não entendi muito bem sua sugestão.

Comment: Opa mencionei o link e acabei me esquecendo de cita-lo. Já editado minha resposta com o link.

Comment: Tem vários problemas em dar uma resposta somente com links. Por favor, leia o post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links

Comment: @PauloSouza Desculpa pela minha resposta incompleta, editei já a resposta para ficar mais adequada aos padrões do SO.

Comment: A solução 1 me parece que não são todos os comando que pode ser substituidos, a solução 2 - eu atualizei o eclipse e ainda continuar com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Eu percebi que esses problemas começaram a acontecer  depois que colocou o computador no domínio, na rede corporativa.

Comment: Que estranho, realmente não faz sentido. Já tentou então desativar os atalhos do Windows?

Comment: Já tentei, o problema é saber onde fazer isso no Windows 10!

Comment: Conseguir resolver trocando os atalhos.

Comment: Trocando os atalhos do Eclipse?